# How can I convert a 256-color bitmap image to DB format?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bmp, bitmapimage, emu8086

I'm looking for a way to convert a 256-color bitmap image into an ASM file that contains inside many `DB` commands with a sequence of BYTES.

I create a bitmap with 256 colors and a resolution of 320x200 pixels.

[image: example of Bitmap with 256 colors and a 320x200 resolution]

I would like a program that allows me to specify the Bitmap to convert. The image must be converted into an .ASM file, into a byte string in emu8086 compatible decimal or binary or hexadecimal format.
Then I will load the converted file (.ASM) into memory (with include command) and read every single byte by coloring the pixels on the screen.

Example of generated .ASM file:

```
DB 10,15,24,32,...
DB 00AH,00FH,018H,020H,...
DB 00001010B,00001111B,00010010B,00100000B,...
```

I try to create a program that read a .TXT file and print the content, but it did not work.
I try to build this program to convert a bitmap file in a text file with .ASM extension and a string of byte inside.

```
org 100h
JMP START

INPUT DB "TEST.TXT", 0
OUTPUT DB "TEST.DB", 0
ERROR DB "FILE NOT FOUND$"

HANDLE DW ?
BUFFER DB 4 DUP(' ') ; i had found this command on internet but i don't know why i need to include it

START:

MOV AH,00H          ; set video mode
MOV AL,03H          ; 80x25 chars with 16 colors
INT 10H             ; Interrupt

; --------------------
; Read the bitmap file
; --------------------

MOV AH,3DH              ; Open the file
MOV AL,0                ; Only in read mode
MOV DX,OFFSET INPUT     ; TEST.TXT
INT 21H                 ; interrupt
JC STOP                 ; If the file not exist print an error

MOV HANDLE,AX           ; i had found this command on internet but i don't know why i need to include it

MOV BX,HANDLE
MOV DX,OFFSET BUFFER
MOV CX,0042H            ; read 42 bytes
MOV AH,3FH         
INT 21H


MOV HANDLE,0000H

READ:

MOV DL,[0124H]      ; print first byte of txt file from 0124H memory location
MOV AH,02H          ; print a char on screen
INT 21H             ; Interrupt

; close the file

MOV AH,3EH
MOV BX,HANDLE
INT 21H

JMP EXIT

STOP:
MOV DX,OFFSET ERROR
MOV AH,9
INT 21H


EXIT:
ret
```

Thanks to all who will answer me.

Comment: Questions asking for ready-made programs are off topic on this site.  If instead you want to learn how to write such a program yourself, that would be on topic.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question.
I tried to make a program but without success.
I'll try to post the source code.
Thank you

Comment: it might be easier to write such a program in a high-level language you are familiar with.  You don't have to program your development tools in the same language as the program you want to use them for.

Comment: I'd use Unix text processing tools like `xxd | sed` or something to turn spaces into the bytes into `0..h` and comma separator.  `xxd` is a hexdump program; I'd look for options to output raw hex without line numbers.  Or I'd just use NASM syntax `%incbin "foo.bmp"` to have the assembler read in the binary file itself, instead of turning the binary into source code.  I don't know if EMU8086's assembler has a binary-include directive.

Comment: `BUFFER` is 4 bytes long and program reads 66 bytes (42h). `Handle` is changed to 0000h so You lost access to file `test.txt`. `[0124h]` is probably some garbage in memory

Comment: @PeterCordes The problem with doing `incbin "foo.bmp" is that you need to find where the actual data is, which isn't always consistent. (I've attempted this and found that for different pictures the file is arranged totally differently and I couldn't figure out what the actual pattern was, so I wasn't able to actually create a program to extract the raw info that could be displayed on a vga screen)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> BUFFER DB 4 DUP(' ') ; i had found this command on internet but i don't know why i need to include it
> ```

You need it because you will want to use some memory buffer where you can store (part of) the .BMP file that you use as input.
What this particular `db 4 dup(' ')` does is reserving a small 4-byte portion of memory to serve as a *BUFFER* (from looking at the label name). That value 4 is important here because it limits what you can do with this buffer. eg. Your program reads 0042H bytes which is much more than the buffer can accommodate. The buffer overflows and the effect on the program will be disastrous!

> ```
> MOV CX,0042H            ; read 42 bytes
> ```

Hoping for a typo here, but do know that 0042H is not the same as 42 bytes. It is 66 bytes.

> ```
> MOV HANDLE,AX           ; i had found this command on internet but i don't know why i need to include it
> ```

When opening a file (like you did), DOS gives back a handle for the opened file. This is a number by which DOS can identify the file in all the subsequent interactions that you plan to undertake concerning this file. Working with a word-sized number is much easier than continually having to refer to the file via its name (which could include a path as well).

> ```
> MOV HANDLE,0000H
> ...
> MOV AH,3EH
> MOV BX,HANDLE
> INT 21H
> ```

Once you've reset the *HANDLE* variable, you should no longer be using it in the CloseFile operation.

> ```
> MOV DL,[0124H]      ; print first byte of txt file from 0124H memory location
> ```

The assembler knows best! Use the name for the buffer and write: `mov dl, BUFFER`. The square brackets are optional when using emu8086.

---

I wrote a demo that converts a 320x200 256-color .BMP file into a .TXT file filled with `db` lines. This is a good starting point for what you ultimately need. It's **just a starting point** because:

- you need to prompt the user to provide the filename(s)
- you need to include suitable error messages
- you need to *not* skip the file headers but rather parse them, so you can:

  - verify whether the .BMP file is a valid bitmap file
  - support a bitmap with dimensions other than 320 x 200
  - support a bitmap with an alternative orientation
- you need to *not* skip the color table but rather use it, so you can show the picture as it was intended, color-wise

The program was tested on a true MS-DOS machine. It ran blazingly fast, but I'm not sure about how fast/slow emu8086 can run this.

```
    ORG     256

    mov     dx, OFFSET TxtF
    xor     cx, cx
    mov     ah, 3Ch     ; DOS.CreateFile
    int     21h         ; -> AX CF
    jc      Exit
    mov     TxtH, ax

    mov     dx, OFFSET BmpF
    mov     ax, 3D00h   ; DOS.OpenFile
    int     21h         ; -> AX CF
    jc      Exit
    mov     BmpH, ax

    mov     dx, 14+40+1024  ; Skip .BMP headers and color table
    xor     cx, cx
    mov     bx, ax
    mov     ax, 4200h   ; DOS.SeekFile
    int     21h         ; -> DX:AX CF
    jc      Exit

    mov     bp, (320*200)/16
OuterLoop:
    mov     dx, OFFSET BmpS
    mov     cx, 16
    mov     bx, BmpH
    mov     ah, 3Fh     ; DOS.ReadFile
    int     21h         ; -> AX CF
    jc      Exit
    cmp     ax, cx
    jne     Exit

    mov     di, OFFSET TxtS+3
    mov     si, OFFSET BmpS
InnerLoop:
    lodsb
    aam     100
    add     ah, '0'
    mov     [di], ah
    aam
    add     ax, '00'
    xchg    al, ah
    mov     [di+1], ax
    add     di, 4
    loop    InnerLoop

    mov     dx, OFFSET TxtS
    mov     cx, 68
    mov     bx, TxtH
    mov     ah, 40h     ; DOS.WriteFile
    int     21h         ; -> AX CF
    jc      Exit

    dec     bp
    jnz     OuterLoop

    mov     bx, BmpH
    mov     ah, 3Eh     ; DOS.CloseFile
    int     21h         ; -> AX CF

    mov     bx, TxtH
    mov     ah, 3Eh     ; DOS.CloseFile
    int     21h         ; -> AX CF

Exit:
    mov     ax, 4C00h   ; DOS.Terminate
    int     21h
; ------------------------------
    ALIGN   2
BmpS    db  16 dup 0
TxtS    db  'db ???', 15 dup (',???'), 13, 10
BmpH    dw  0
TxtH    dw  0
BmpF    db  'EXAMPO4.BMP', 0    ; 65078 bytes
TxtF    db  'EXAMPO4.TXT', 0    ; 272000 bytes
```

What my output looked like:

> ```
> db 000,003,000,017,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,012,151,177,113,087
> db 125,151,151,151,140,151,175,158,183,189,245,246,216,244,224,226
> db 165,164,148,132,125,087,062,076,115,103,069,066,048,158,097,001
> db 059,000,091,091,005,012,000,000,000,011,029,106,024,005,048,062
> db 224,212,204,212,183,189,062,214,184,196,160,237,125,162,180,190
> db 000,003,000,017,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,012,151,177,113,087
> db 125,151,151,151,140,151,175,158,183,189,245,246,216,244,224,226
> db 165,164,148,132,125,087,062,076,115,103,069,066,048,158,097,001
> db 059,000,091,091,005,012,000,000,000,011,029,106,024,005,048,062
> db 224,212,204,212,183,189,062,214,184,196,160,237,125,162,180,190
> --- 3990 more lines ---
> ```

Comment: I have problems with emu8086 with AAM command because emu8086 doesn't want operands with this command but only "AAM".
Can you suggest me some similar command?
I also changed the command "ALIGN 2" with "ALIGN EQU 2" because otherwise emu8086 releases error. I did well?
Anyway thanks! You've been really kind.

Comment: @Leonardo You can replace the `aam 100` instruction by its encoding `db 0D4h, 100`. I don't think that `ALIGN EQU 2` is quite the same as what I wrote, but you could just as easy simply remove the alignment directive. It is not essential for a functioning program.

Comment: I tried to replace "AAM" instruction with DB 0D4H,64H and i had removed "ALIGN EQU 2" but in the txt file i can read only theese lines.
ÿÿÿ255ÿ255ÿ255ÿ255,050,053,053,255,050,053,053,255,050,053,053,255

Comment: @Leonardo emu8086 is renowned for its many bugs. Maybe the format string gets mis-interpreted. Try changing `TxtS    db  'db ???', 15 dup (',???'), 13, 10` into `TxtS db "db ...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...", 13, 10`.

Comment: I had already read that emu8086 has several bugs.
What assembler are you using to compile?
I would like to try the same one you use.

Comment: @Leonardo This little program I assembled with an home-brewed assembler, but the rest of the time I mostly use FASM (flatassembler.net). Mind you, the syntaxes will differ a bit: emu8086 uses **M**ASM style, while FASM uses **N**ASM style. eg. loading an address changes from `mov si, OFFSET BmpS` into `mov si, BmpS`.