# How can I convert DB DOS Assembly Bytes To A 256 Colour Bitmap?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-16, bmp, ida

I was really pleased to find the following post, on this Forum :-

[Here is the Post Converting a 256 Colour Bitmap Image To DB Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76433792/how-can-i-convert-a-256-color-bitmap-image-to-db-format)

I would like to do the reverse of that.

Convert DB Bytes From a DOS Game Executable that I analysed in a free Older version of IDA, that supports analysing DOS Executables to a 320x200 Bitmap Image.

I am thinking If I get a successful output image, it may be several joined together, as the DB Bytes might correspond, to different Bitmap Graphics in the Game ?

I also found and read the following Webpage :-

[Graphics Modes In DOS Info](https://atrevida.comprenica.com/atrtut07.html)

After Reading about how Bytes are organized in the A000:0000 segment and how VGA Game Graphics work, in DOS Assembly Code.

I did a search for A000 in the decompiled SWOTL.exe File in this version of IDA

And found the Following :-

[image: Search For A000 In EXE File In IDA]

I then opened 0A000H in IDA and got the following :-

[image: After opening 0A000H]

I then clicked on 25BEh and got the following :-

[image: Segment 2486]

I also clicked on 6000h and got other Segments with DB Bytes, I am thinking that those DB Bytes may be the bytes corresponding to the pixels of the Graphics i.e. position ?

I would like to use, the DB Bytes for the 2486 Segment, and try and convert them to a bitmap Image.

Here is a link to the DOS Game Executable :-

[SWOTL.exe File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6pi1osmb8j3fjauqullnb/Swotl.exe?rlkey=dw2x82ivijx10ssjdhqo2ekkt&dl=0)

And here is a Link to the Lines of DB Bytes Text :-

[DB Bytes Text File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fd3coa8izuuj2a9oy4gts/DB-Bytes-Text.txt?rlkey=rvgvz0i6n8x3s0ey1lndjgkbm&dl=0)

Could someone tell me how I can do this please ? based on the other Stackoverflow Post ?

I looked for other similar posts, but couldn't get the answer I needed.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One idea: 1) Obtain the disassembled list as a text file. 2) Specify the
range of lines which contain the DB bytes. 3) Write a C, Python or Perl program to
extract the DB bytes, convert ascii strings to RGB bytes, and format them as a bmp file
by adding appropriate header. Does it make sense to you? If yes, can you upload the file 1)
to some accessible location?

Comment: Hi tshiono, Many thanks for your reply, you mean upload the DOS Game executable ? I could upload it to Dropbox.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I wanted to mean "the disassembled list" to upload . Is that possible? I don't need the whole data. You can trim the file to contain the DB lines.

Comment: Hi tshiono, I have edited my post, and now have links to the DOS Game executable File and the DB Bytes Text File

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'll try to analyze the data. BTW the `DB Bytes Text File` contains just 330 byte data which will correspond to very small image. Is that all?

Comment: Many thanks tshiono, there are other Segments proceeding and after that have DB Bytes. Could you maybe look at the executable in IDA if you have it ? Maybe that isn't the correct data I have there ? The Plane external graphics are quite small in the game.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll look into the uploaded executable file. Could you allow me a day or two to come back? I'd appreciate your patience, cheers.

Comment: Thats great tshiono, thankyou so much seg005, I think is very relevant to the graphics, there are alot of db bytes in that section.

Comment: My eventual aim is, to replace for fun, the Plane Shape Graphics in the game with new bitmaps i.e. have different Plane shapes. It's the Plane Shape Graphics, I wan't the most.

Comment: After a quick survey, I've noticed the uploaded `Swotl.exe` file does not contain meaningful
image data. Instead the accompanied `*.PAC` files look contain image data as you posted
[here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32031/help-needed-with-finding-image-data-in-dos-game-file). I assume your immediate aim is to improve your C program
provided in the post. Am I right?

Comment: Hi tshiono, yes that's right, if you could help me with that post, that would be really good. Many thanks tshiono.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately the link to the dropbox where you have uploaded the image files and batch files seems to have expired. Can you renew the link? BR.

Comment: Yes I will renew it for tshiono.

Comment: Hi tshiono, I am about to go out for a few, I will sort out a new Dropbox link later for you if that is okay ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Please take your time. I'll be waiting for the new link. BR.

Comment: A few hours, sorry forgot to type hours

Comment: Hi tshiono, I have a new Link posted to the files on dropbox, on the Stack Exchange post. Eddie )

Comment: Thank you for the prompt action. I've successfully downloaded the files. I'll start with understanding the contents. Please allow me a while to come back. Cheers.

Comment: The reason tshiono, behind the Folder Names Test_Duds in pnlswotl and pacswotl, is that my Sister Jenny's nickname for me is Druds, she used to call me that instead of Edward, when she was little.

Comment: Thankyou so much tshiono, I very much appreciate, all the help you can give me. ))